# Intersection of two or more sorted sets

Tags: redis, set, nosql

I have two sorted sets, and want to make intersection, ie. `(age BETWEEN 25, 35) AND (salary BETWEEN 250, 350)`

Is there a better way regarding efficiency than:

```
ZUNIONSTORE t_age 1 age WEIGHTS 1
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE t_age -inf (25
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE t_age (35 +inf
ZINTERSTORE result 2 salary t_age WEIGHTS 1 0
ZRANGEBYSCORE result 250 350
```

Comment: Do you mean `ZINTERSTORE result 2 salary t_age WEIGHTS 1 0
` with the zero?

Comment: An hypothetical command ZRANGEBYSCORESTORE that stores the results would have helped to aggregate data. Also an exclusive version of ZREMRANGEBYSCORE...

Comment: Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/redis-db/ZRANGEBYSCORE/redis-db/8TBbISxd244/Rtl5VNdQWAMJ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first check which `ZSET` has less elements with [ZCARD](http://redis.io/commands/zcard), and clone and trim the shorter one.

Second, you are leaving 2 leftovers. You can reuse the same auxiliary `ZSET` to have a faster cleanup.

I also wanted to suggest [DUMP](http://redis.io/commands/dump) and [RESTORE](http://redis.io/commands/restore) for the clone, but for the sorted sets case ZUNIONSTORE is actually much faster.
Here's a timing of both for a 1M elements set:

```
1) 1) (integer) 14
   2) (integer) 1444165498
   3) (integer) 936762
   4) Complexity info: N:1000000,M:1000000
   5) 1) "ZUNIONSTORE"
      2) "temp3"
      3) "1"
      4) "temp1"
      5) "WEIGHTS"
      6) "1"
2) 1) (integer) 13
   2) (integer) 1444165421
   3) (integer) 3166360
   4)
   5) 1) "evalsha"
      2) "48286113cfe4b389d516e98646e5f4e086decc34"
      3) "2"
      4) "temp1"
      5) "temp2"
      6) "0"
```

Comment: This is literally the initial answer I had in mind. While the cardinality remark is important I'm guessing given the age/salary context that both set have the same members. But then I thought of something else which after benchmarking performs ~x35 better. I intend to share that at the upcoming Redis Developers Day... so stay tuned :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber does it involve lua scripting?

Comment: @ItamarHaber just trying to guess, two ZRANGEBYSCORE, two multiple SADD, and one SINTERSTORE? (I won't be at the conference `:)`)

Comment: We're planning to write up on everything from RDD, so the community can benefit even if specific members couldn't attend. My approach requires a different data structure (currently I'm using a Hash so to query I'm just doing a bunch of HGETs). BTW, what's the cardinality of your sets? I did my "benchmarks" on 100K members but real numbers always help.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I have about 20k of members so they are probably not making an issue for redis.

Answer (score 4):

So the idea I had is to use a different data structures, namely a quadtree, to achieve the same type of query more efficiently. You can see my little POC (Redis Quadtree in Hash) made with "object-oriented" Lua  at: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/c1ffda42d86b314ea701

Note: you should know that this sparked an extremely interesting discussion before, during and after the Redis Developers Day. The intermediate result is the new [indexing page](http://redis.io/topics/indexes) but in the near future Redis is likely to be added with a higher-level API that will make n-dimensional indexing trivial to use.

Comment: That would be great; tnx for helping this functionality go into the Redis core.