# How to store 'expireable' time intervals in Redis?

Tags: redis

I have a key which changes value depending on the time interval. I would also like to only keep the last `X` intervals so I don't store unnecessary, older data.

For an example:

in range 1490572800000-1490659199999 (today) it should return value `a`, 
and for values in range 1490659200000-1490745599999 it should return value `b`.

I tried implementing this with hash:

```
hmset mykey 1490572800000-1490659199999 "a" 1490659200000-1490745599999 "b"
```

then query with `hkeys` or `hscan` and check if my timestamp is in the range of any hash field but that seems kinda off...

I handled 'expirations' by keeping a separate list where I `RPUSH` new intervals in a list `mykey-intervals`. If `LLEN mykey-intervals > X`, I need to drop the oldest interval. Then, I use `LPOP mykey-intervals` to retrieve the oldest interval which I then `HDEL` from `mykey`.

Can this be done simpler/better?

-- EDIT --

The solution I ended up with using sorted sets:

The periods used in the example below are: a[5-10], b[11-16], c[17-22] and the timestamp im searching for is 7.

```
ZADD start-times 5 a 11 b 17 c
ZADD end-times 10 a 16 b 22 c
ZUNIONSTORE temp-start 1 start-times WEIGHTS 1
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE temp-start (7 +inf
ZUNIONSTORE temp-end 1 end-times WEIGHTS 1
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE temp-end -inf (7
ZINTERSTORE result 2 temp-start temp-end
```

First I created 2 zsets, one for storing interval start times and another for end times. Then, I copied the start times into another (temporary) zset and removed all start times after my timestamp leaving me only with start times before the timestamp. Then I copied the end times and removed all end times before the timestamp. Intersecting the sets leaves me with only the intervals that cover my desired timestamp.

Comment: Why not store the value a in a sorted set using the time as a key, then use ZRANGEBYSCORE to retrieve the value between certain times? You can then ZREMRANGEBYSCORE to remove old values.

Comment: Which time is the score? The beginning of the interval? Could you write a simple example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Using short 'times' to make it neater,) say you wanted to store 'a' at times between 5 and 10, you could store your value at any time between them, say 7, using `ZADD mytimes 7 "a"`, and then retrieve that value later using `ZRANGEBYSCORE mytimes 5 10`, which would return a single value, 'a'.

Later when you get to higher times, you could remove say all times less than 100 by using `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE mytimes 0 100`.

Alternatively you could just round down all times to the nearest interval and store the value at that time, so you'd store 'a' at 5, and any value between 5 and 10 would be rounded down. Depends on your data whether it will work that way.

Comment: I was seriously overcomplicating this in my head... Trying to figure out how to set the score of 2 timestamps... I think I know where to go from here, thanks!

Comment: I just tried implementing this and I think I've bumped into a wall... If I only set the start or end time of the interval as the score, how can I check if my timestamp is in the interval? If you look at my hash answer, I supplied only the timestamp I wish to check, not the whole interval. If I `ZADD mytimes 5 "a"` for an interval 5-10 I can not use `ZRANGEBYSCORE` since I am not aware of the interval, only a timestamp I wish to check. If my timestamp is 12, I can't know if "a" is in my interval or not. Any advice?

Comment: Are the intervals consistent? Is it always 24 hours? Then you could round down to the nearest 24hours.

Comment: Maybe you could store the value both at the start and end of the range, and retrieve it by using ZRANGEBYSCORE mytimes 5 +inf LIMIT 0 1, that way you'll just get back the first value after your current time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these approaches:

- See [Intersection of two or more sorted sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32911604/3160475) - in your case age can be the interval's start time and salary the end time.
- Explore redimension: https://github.com/RedisLabs/lua-redimension

Comment: I haven't used zsets before so I am not sure if I can do it better, would you mind taking a look at my edit? Also, is this solution better performant-wise compared to the hash solution I came up with initially? Because it seems like a lot of work copying and removing data.

Comment: Looks like your edit was adapted correctly. It will be more efficient than scanning an entire hash imo, but indeed the zset operations are expensive as well.