# copy (backup) a redis key to another key

Tags: redis, copy

I am looking for an effecient way to copy the content of one redis key (of type [zrange](https://redis.io/commands/zrange) ) to another redis key (for the purpose of taking a backup of previous scores);

For example for key `my_score:`
`
'a': 100,
'b': 200,
'c': 300

The type of operation I am looking for is something similar to
`prev_score = my_score`

after certain time interval above redis data will undergo some changes (through some other codes) and need to re-evaluate the changes. This time the new values will be say

`'a': 150,
'b': 250,
'c': 300`

Now I need to compare the changes since the last check so that i can compare the type of changes in each indexes.

Please not the flowings:

1. this operation is within the same database (not from one redis instance to another redis instance)
2. I have special reason to use zrange and not other redis data types which cannot be changed
3. I can achive this by using `zadd` for each index but I am looking for a single redis command or more effecient one.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - `ZUNIONSTORE prev_score 1 my_score`.

Details are in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911604/intersection-of-two-or-more-sorted-sets/32980086#32980086)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DUMP` and `RESTORE`.

```
str = DUMP myscore
RESTORE another_key 0 str
```

And if your key has expire time, you could first use `PTTL key` to get the expire time in ms, and then `RESTORE another_key expire_time str`.